# Need user to update only their profile image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Am using the paperclip gem and i need users to update only their image. The problem is i get the following error when i try to upload the image. `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` my update photo method looks like this:

```
def upload_photo
 if @user.update_attributes(:profile_image => params[:user][:profile_image])
    redirect_to(edit_user_path)
 else
    render 'upload_photo'
 end
end
```

my user model has `attr_accessible :profile_image` defined and i have tried using `update_attribute` to no avail. And finally my view looks like this.

```
<%= form_for(@user, :url => upload_photo_user_path, :html => { :multipart => true, :method => :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :profile_image, :class => "btn btn-success" %>
  <%= f.submit "Upload photo" %>
<% end %>
```

Any code examples are highly appreciated since i have really tried almost everything.

Comment: Can you please show us your model?

Comment: Can you give more of the callback trace (with line numbers) and the full controller too? Just saying `@user` isn't going to work without setting it first.